# Android Widget Application State

Tags: android, singleton, widget, state, status

I have a Android Widget, Configuration Activities, and a heavily used Android Service full of functions.  I want to maintain global application state/status that can be referenced from any of the above locations.  The state I am referring to is application domain specific status.  For example STARTED, LEVEL1, LEVEL2 etc.  So I would like to know the following:

1) What are the advantages of Global Singleton for keeping this state/status vs. subclassing 
   the Android Application and using it as the Singleton?

2) I want the state to be a recoverable singleton.  So I need to save it off when the App 
   gets shutdown, process terminated.  Where is the right place to save off the overall application state?  the terminate method on Application can be overridden but its not really guaranteed to get called.  So I am looking also for the point at which to save off the application state.  Its not clear to me. The Activity is not the global application, neither is the widget nor the service, so where can I tell that the application is being shutdown/terminated and saveoff the application state.

3) Is their anything wrong with initializing the state in Application.onStart()?

Comment: there is no `Application.onStart()`

Comment: correct I was referring to Application.onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Service?  That is a good place to keep live state. AFAIK it is guaranteed that Service is a singleton, and onCreate() and/or onStartCommand() offer places appropriate for initializations.  I'm unclear any guarantee that onDestroy() gets called, but the docs seem to say it will:

"A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is effectively terminated." [ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Well the first question is really where the custom application state should reside.  Suppose your app has n services? would you make one such service the one that kept the shared state? I think not. Take the general case 1 app, n services, y widgets.  It seems that this shared state of the app really belongs with the application and not any of its components right?

Comment: keep in mind this is about sharing and not just storing.  True you can store anywhere and retrieve anywhere, but this does not provide synched sharing.  Its also not logically a preference.

Comment: > make one such service the one that kept the shared state? I think not.  Why not?  According to the docs "A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation .. to supply functionality for other applications to use."  It is a singleton, long-running, and available to other components or even other apps.  Seems a natural component type all ready to keep (and persist) "custom application state."

Comment: Why pick it over the Android App subclass?  And who wants to incur the costs of calling a service just to get a state?  The application is available to everything that has a context without binding.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What are the advantages of Global Singleton for keeping this state/status vs. subclassing the Android Application and using it as the Singleton?

If by "Global Singleton" you mean a static data member, there are no advantages or disadvantages of significance either way, IMHO.

> 2) I want the state to be a recoverable singleton. So I need to save it off when the App gets shutdown, process terminated. Where is the right place to save off the overall application state?

Every time it changes, more or less.

> The Activity is not the global application, neither is the widget nor the service, so where can I tell that the application is being shutdown/terminated and saveoff the application state.

You aren't told. Hence, you save it every time it changes. Your static data member, `Application` object, or whatever is a cache for persistent data -- everything else is subject to utter destruction. (insert evil maniacal laugh here)

> 3) Is their anything wrong with initializing the state in Application.onCreate()? (corrected)

I assume you mean `onCreate()`. You are on the main application thread, and so I/O might be kicked off in `onStart()` but should occur on an `AsyncTask` or other background thread.

Comment: 3) part of the initialization refers is obtained by doing registerReceiver(null, Intent) to get system values. Would this fit in onCreate as far an ANR, or would it make more sense to pass an initialization request Intent to a service?

Comment: @Androider: `registerReceiver()` should take microseconds and should not be a problem.

Comment: 2) is it enough to save off new state in static variable of Application subclass (or Singleton), or do I also need to store it persistently using something like shared preferences. So what I am asking here is do I really need to do a syncronized method call on the static data and both update the value in the singleton and at the same time update its value in the shared preferences?

Comment: @Androider: " do I really need to do a syncronized method call on the static data and both update the value in the singleton and at the same time update its value in the shared preferences?" -- I have no idea. It is your data. You can do with it whatever you want. The time gap between when the data logically changes and when those changes get persisted represents a period of time in which those changes will be lost if things go sideways. Typically, since persisting data takes time, you spawn an `AsyncTask` or something to do the persisting and hope for the best.

Comment: I was referring only to persisting a status variable of the application to represent custom application state

Comment: Do you think that I could preserve a status value String if I did a single syncronized method call to store in shared preferences and update in singleton. Syncing on the status variable itself?

Comment: btw are SharedPreferences available in onCreate() I don't see that a Context gets passed in. What is the earliest point you could access SharedPreferences?

Comment: Do you think it makes sense to start a service to initialize this shared status or it is better to do it inside Application Subclass onCreate() method?

Comment: @Androider: "I was referring only to persisting a status variable of the application to represent custom application state" -- that phrase means something to you, but not to me. "btw are SharedPreferences available in onCreate() I don't see that a Context gets passed in." -- `Application` is a `Context`.

Comment: Well it is more general that in sounds.  I am referring to a value that is not really a preference, or user set value but the intrinsic state of the application itself.  What I am hearing is basically that Android can shutdown without notice, so what I am saying is that if I have an important String value (in my case its a status), does it make sense to update and store in one method call.  To have a set method that does basically two operations sets the static String in a singleton (like application or custom singleton), and also sets shared preferences with the value.